# Como quebrar a linha de uma label automaticamente?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **=** .NET Framework 4.0
>   **=** Visual C#

Tenho um problema quanto à *labels*, quando atribuo um valor à propriedade `text` e este valor é muito grande, ele "quebra" seu container, ultrapassando as bordas, com isso, a parte que fica fora dos limites não é possível de ser vista. O que estou procurando é uma solução para isso, quebrar o texto automaticamente (a partir do espaço, não quebrar a palavra) quando ele atinge 5 pixels da borda direita, porém, não tenho ideia de como fazê-lo.

Já pensei em desativar a propriedade `AutoSize`, mas é inviável, pois a altura do texto também fica limitada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode estar fazendo algo como isto:

```
label1.MaximumSize = new Size(100, 0);
label1.AutoSize = true;
label1.Text = "Stack Overflow em Portugues";
```

O resultado será:

[image]

<sub>[`Fonte`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3680595/1608936)</sub>